# Show object with different name in an app

Tags: label

Is there a way to show the contact object in a custom app with a different name (let's call it organizer) but in other apps it should display as Contacts?

Also, I only want the change to been seen for users who are in a specific profile.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an "All or None" setting, you cannot specify the change to a Label for only 1 profile.